# How to set password reset url to a mobile deeplink using Flask Security?

Tags: python, redirect, single-page-application, deep-linking, flask-security

Gist of the problem is, I'm not developing an SPA, I'm developing a mobile app, with a backend in Flask. FlaskSecurityToo has provided me with some great features, and I'm now trying to use their password reset functionality. Here's my gripe.

I want to have the email send a deeplink, which users on the mobile app will click and get sent to the password reset form on the app. There's no UI view for this. But FlaskSecurityToo has logic that requires the server is first hit to validate the token, then redirects them to whatever has `REDIRECT_HOST` set. Which works great when I set the `REDIRECT_BEHAVIOR` as `spa`

**Is there a way to tell Flask "Hey, don't worry about the need to validate the token from the initially provided password reset email, let the UI/Mobile app make the call to determine that whenever they want" from the provided configuration?** Thus, relaxing the constraint on the host name / details of the url for a password reset, as long as a token exists? Or is this abusing some of the principles of FlaskSecurity that I don't grasp yet?

My current plan is to let it open a mobile browser, and hopefully the redirect forces the app open? I have little experience with deeplinks, so I'm testing and probing things as I learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about current FS behavior - here is a suggestion (not clean but it would be interesting if it was all you need) - the POST /reset/ endpoint is stand-alone - you don't have to call GET first - the POST will ALSO verify the token is valid. So the issue becomes how to generate the link for the email that has what you want. FS currently doesn't allow to configure this (that could be an enhancement) - but in 4.0.0 you can easily replace the MailUtil class and have your implementation of send_mail look for template='reset_instructions'. Now - at this point the email has already been rendered - so you would have to parse the body and rewrite the url (keeping the token intact). Ugly but doable - is this sufficient? If so I can see a few simple improvements in FS to allow more flexibility around emails.

Comment: I was definitely thinking about this approach, but let me restate what you said to make sure before I try it later tonight. Extend the MailUtil class, override the [send mail method](https://github.com/Flask-Middleware/flask-security/blob/master/flask_security/mail_util.py#L40), and use when  `template == 'reset_instructions'` to know when to parse the `body` and `html`, trying to replace the `reset_link` url to whatever my deep link is, correct?

Comment: Also, the GET seems to also attach an identity and an email of the user. Is there harm in adding email to the initial URL, for login upon reset?

Comment: Essentially yes - ugly I know but lets see if that moves you forward. Not sure what you mean in second question - upon successful POST to /reset/<token> user will be automatically logged in.

Comment: Can confirm your solution did work. And I've dealt with uglier solutions to feature requests, so for now I'm happy this was all it took. I have yet to test the full flow from a mobile perspective, but shouldn't matter.

Oh, and my question was about making the `GET` with the email provided link. It adds `identity` and `email` if possible to the link before redirect. Not sure I absolutely need that for log in to still succeed after reset. [This code in particular](https://github.com/Flask-Middleware/flask-security/blob/951e4b56e1c186cc29b29b57283db38e0f21505f/docs/openapi.yaml#L399)

Comment: Glad you are moving forward. As to GET response - email/identity not required - it is returned to improve SPA UX. The token alone is used for verification and identity.